# OAuth registration and Google Drive API

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I would like to access the content of my own Google Drive from a Python script that I will run locally.

I have found the pydrive module, which seems to be suitable for my purpose.

However, I struggle setting up authentication. It seems that I need to create OAuth credentials. As part of this, in https://console.developers.google.com, I need to configure a consent screen.

This is where I get stuck. As "User Type" I am only able to select "External". Then I need to enter an "authorized domain", an "application homepage link", and an "application privacy policy link". The domain needs to be a top private domain. Neither do I have such a domain registered, nor do I have a corresponding server running.

Am I on the right track at all? Or do I need to setup OAuth differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you just want to run your code locally - all you need is to enable the Drive API and to download a `credentials.json`file into your work directory

- The `credentials.json` file contains your among others your `Client ID`, `Client Secret` and `Project ID`
- The easiest way to do it is by pressing `Enable Drive API` from the [Drive API quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) specifying `Desktop application`

---

- If you want to create the credentials manually - for a Desktop application you do not need to specify any domains or homepage links  - only the Application name
- The next step would be creating `Credentials-> OAuth Client ID`
- Specify `Other` and you will not be promted for additional information